# How can I achieve following layout in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, tabmenu

I have a layout as follows for iOS app development.
[image: Mock up]

The layout contains following parts:

1. **Collapsing toolbar**: This `view` should work like in android i.e. on
   scrolling it must be collapsed.
2. **Tab menu**: This is tab menu. On swiping, the `tableview` must be updated as per menu selected. On `scrolling` tab menu must be fixed at top.
3. **Tableview** : This is simply a `tableview` contains data as per menu selected in tab menu.
4. **Bottom tab**: This is `UITabbarMenu`.

I tried with following approach:

[image]

I used [Pagingkit](https://github.com/kazuhiro4949/PagingKit) library for tab menu. I created height of vProductList (parent view of `tabbar` and `tableview`) to height of device screen.

The problem appeared when tableview was inside `scrollview`. The problem was `tableview` and `scrollview` acts differently on scrolling. So to remove this I disable scrolling of `tableview` at first and enabled in `viewDidScroll` method on condition that the tab menu view is at (0,0) point of screen. But, one has to scroll twice to get the effect. This felt glitchy. How can I achieve smooth scrolling with this approach? Is there any library that can solve this problem?

Comment: Check out this tutorial: https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/how-to-create-a-stretchable-tableviewheader-in-ios-ee9ed049aba3

Comment: Thanks but I need to implement tab menu between collapsing toolbar and tableview.  Is there any way?

Answer (score 5):

This is how you can work this out.

**View Hierarchy:**

[image]

You can use a `UICollectionView` to create the `Tabbar`.
A `UITableView` to handle the data when a `tab` is `selected`.
To handle the data in both `UICollectionView` and `UITableView`, create a `ViewModel`. Here is an example of how you can,

```
enum ListType: Int {
    case fruits, animals, vegetables
}

class ViewModel {
    let tabs: [ListType] = [.fruits, .animals, .vegetables]

    let fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Grapes", "Papaya", "Apple", "Banana", "Grapes", "Papaya", "Apple", "Banana", "Grapes", "Papaya"]
    let animals = ["Rabbit", "Monkey", "Bear", "Deer", "Rabbit", "Monkey", "Bear", "Deer", "Rabbit", "Monkey", "Bear", "Deer"]
    let vegetables = ["Carrot", "Potato", "Cucumber", "Spinach", "Carrot", "Potato", "Cucumber", "Spinach", "Carrot", "Potato", "Cucumber", "Spinach"]

    func numberOfTabs() -> Int {
        return self.tabs.count
    }

    func tab(at index: Int) -> ListType {
        return self.tabs[index]
    }

    func numberOfRows(for listType: ListType) -> Int {
        switch listType {
        case .fruits: return fruits.count
        case .animals: return animals.count
        case .vegetables: return vegetables.count
        }
    }

    func element(at index: Int, for listType: ListType) -> String? {
        switch listType {
        case .fruits: return fruits[index]
        case .animals: return animals[index]
        case .vegetables: return vegetables[index]
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I’ve created

1. an `enum ListType` that identifies the `types of tabs` in `collectionView` and the data that is to be presented in the `tableView`.
2. a `class ViewModel` that handles the `dataSource` for both `collectionView` and `tableView`.

Let’s create a `UIViewController` with some `outlets`, i.e.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collapsingViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    private let viewModel = ViewModel()
    private var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .left)
    }
}
```

Add the methods for `UITableViewDataSource`

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let selectedIndex = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first?.row, let listType = ListType(rawValue: selectedIndex) {
            return self.viewModel.numberOfRows(for: listType)
        }
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let selectedIndex = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first?.row, let listType = ListType(rawValue: selectedIndex) {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = self.viewModel.element(at: indexPath.row, for: listType)
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

`UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate` methods

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.viewModel.numberOfTabs()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionCell
        cell.textLabel.text = String(describing: self.viewModel.tab(at: indexPath.row)).capitalized
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

To handle the `collapsing view` on `tableView` `scroll`, implement `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` method and handle the `collapse and expand` based on the `lastContentOffset` of the `tableView`, i.e.

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView == self.tableView {
            if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)) {
                //Scrolled to bottom
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                    self.collapsingViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0.0
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            }
            else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < self.lastContentOffset || scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0) && (self.collapsingViewHeightConstraint.constant != 150.0)  {
                //Scrolling up, scrolled to top
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                    self.collapsingViewHeightConstraint.constant = 150.0
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            }
            else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > self.lastContentOffset) && self.collapsingViewHeightConstraint.constant != 0.0 {
                //Scrolling down
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                    self.collapsingViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0.0
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            }
            self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works great. But, is there any way to show page swiping effect on swiping tableview horizontally?

Comment: You need only horizontal swipe in tableView?

Comment: I was trying to get this kind of swiping effect while swiping tableview horizontally.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tamanyan/SwiftPageMenu/master/screen_captures/1.gif

Comment: Ya, sure @PGDev

Comment: @AkashRaghani What exactly is not working?